# marquee tag not working on hover effect

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="padding-left:100px;width:600px;">

        <h4><label style="color:#000">UPDATED NEWS</label></h4>
        <marquee id="test" behavior="scroll" direction="up" height="100" width="350" scrolldelay="100" scrollamount="2" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
        <ul type="square" >
        <li><a href="#">Strategy / Roadmap</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Porting & upgrades</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product / Apps</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Platform Davelopment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Testing & Security</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Enterprise Integration</a></li>
        </ul>
        </marquee>
    </div>
```

I'm using the following HTML piece of code to stop my content on hover effect:

Comment: You should know that the `<marquee>` tags has been deprecated  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: It's working fine check http://jsfiddle.net/ndp35jov/1/

Comment: marquee is deprecated though if you are using use onmouseout instead of onMouseOut

Comment: Don't use `<marquee>` - it's old and slow and clunky and not very nice - use a javascript / [jquery alternative](http://plugins.jquery.com/marquee/)

Comment: You have not closed it </marquee>

Comment: Without a Text How It will work babre..???

Answer (score -1):

```
<marquee id="test" behavior="scroll" direction="up" height="200" scrolldelay="100" scrollamount="2" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();"> TEXT HERE</marquee>
```

But your original code kind of worked anyway, just have the close  tag

Comment: still it is not working...and my exact code is above mention and thanks to all...but please give me answer...